# Yii URL manager routing additional variables not finding a route?

Tags: php, yii, yii-url-manager

My current url manager:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
            'showScriptName'=>false,
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'rules'=>array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                'rest/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                'rest/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ),
```

With regards to the **rest** route

```
http://htt.local/rest/v1/show/2916
```

works!!

```
http://htt.local/rest/v1/candle/2916/from/2015-12-23
Unable to resolve request
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url manager should be like this:

```
'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            'rest/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',

            /* Add this line */
            'rest/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>/from/<date>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            /*  */

            'rest/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
```